# How to use Java Scanner console to input tokens from a String

Tags: java, string, console, token

I have an assignment that asks for a form of input that I'm not familiar with. It requires that the input be one string and them we must pull an int and double from that string. I can't figure out how to do this with the required input statement "console.nextDouble()" and "console.nextInt()". I included the relevant part of the instructions below and the code that I wrote. Any insight on how this is supposed to be written would be helpful.

> Instructions: To get the maximum of 5 points on this part of the
>   assignment, your program must accept input as 4 tokens and verify that
>   the input is in an appropriate format.  The first token will be either
>   "amount" or "years" (without the quotes). If the first token is
>   "amount", the next is the amount of the loan and should be read in
>   using console.nextDouble(). If the first token is "years", the next
>   token is the number of years and should be read in with
>   console.nextInt(). If the first token was "amount", the third token
>   should be "years" and the number of years is read in as the fourth
>   token using console.nextInt(). If the first token was "years", the
>   third token should be "amount" and the amount should be read in with
>   console.nextDouble(). Any other tokens are considered invalid input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Project 2 written by KC");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter the loan amount and loan duration in years,\nfor example amount 3000 years 2");
    String input = console.nextLine();
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    String part1 = parts[0]; 
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String part3= parts[2];
    String part4 = parts[3];
    if (part1.equals("amount")) {
        double amount = console.nextDouble(part2);
        int years = console.nextInt(part4);
    } else if (part1.equalsIgnoreCase("years")){
        int years = console.nextInt(part2);
        double amount = console.nextDouble(part4);
    }
    int years= console.nextInt();
    double rate = loanRate(amount);
    System.out.println("Loan Amount: "+ customFormat(amount));
    System.out.println("Loan Period: " + years + " years");
    System.out.println("Loan Rate: " + rate + "%");
    System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " + customFormat(loanMonthlyPayment(amount, years, rate)));
    System.out.println("Month" + padOnLeft("Balance", 15) + padOnLeft("Payment", 15) + padOnLeft("Remaining", 15));
    System.out.println("Total Payment Amount: " + customFormat(loanTotalPayment(amount, years, rate, (loanMonthlyPayment(amount, years, rate)))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem.You want to extract words from a sentence using Scanner and get the integer and double values.You give this snippet a try.I have modified a part of your code.:-

```
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string:-");
    String st=scan.nextLine();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(st);
    String arr[]=new String[4];
    int i=0;
    double val=0;
    int n=0;
    while(i<4){
        String st1=sc.next();
        arr[i]=st1;
        i++;
    }
    if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("amount")){
    n=Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
    val=Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
}
    if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("years")){
        val=Double.parseDouble(arr[3]);
        n=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`String input = console.nextLine();`

To:

`String input = console.next();`

`next()` should take String types.

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html:

> public String next(Pattern pattern)
>
> Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous
>   invocation of hasNext(Pattern) returned true. If the match is
>   successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched the
>   pattern.
>
> Parameters:
>       pattern - the pattern to scan for Returns:
>       the next token Throws:
>       NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available
>       IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Comment: I feel this answer is lacking the full explination of why this works. Mention how this enures only the first word in the line will be received, allowing him to use `nextDouble()` and what not for the rest

Comment: I can explain further when i get access to a PC again

Comment: And hope someone doesn't come along and post a better formatted answer before then? I'd just fix it up real quick if I were you. Your choice though

Comment: I would if i had access to my PC. But if someone has a better explanation then that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I still can't get this to work. The console.next(); just gives me the first token. I would really appreciate further explanations. Thanks Very Much!

Comment: @Kdiggity: question, have you tried entering multiple strings seperated by spaces?